# OpenWRT - Can't block DNS port (53) from WAN-LAN direction

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, openwrt, dnsmasq

I have a TP-Link WDR4300 router with OpenWRT BarrierBreaker (vargalex build ver. 1.1.7).

I use due to my Raspberry (`SMB, PMA, Plex, etc`) `DDNS` (`duckdns.org`) to reach my Router outside of my LAN (I've tried to configure VPN on the router, but somehow I can't find the right configuration). My services are using theese ports: `139, 445, 8080, 8081, 8877, 56565` but somewhy `53` (`dnsmasq`) port is opened from `WAN` and I can't block it.

`netstat` outputs:

```
netstat -an
```

[image: netstat -an]

```
netstat -pln
```

[image: netstat -pln]

`nslookup` output:

```
> server <myremoteaddress>.duckdns.org
Default Server:  remoteconnection.duckdns.org
Address:  <myipaddress>

> google.com.
Server:  <myremoteaddress>.duckdns.org
Address:  <myipaddress>

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  xxxx:yyyy:400d:zzzz::200e
          ***.***.72.20
          ***.***.72.34
          ***.***.72.45
          ***.***.72.24
          ***.***.72.49
          ***.***.72.44
          ***.***.72.39
          ***.***.72.25
          ***.***.72.30
          ***.***.72.54
          ***.***.72.40
          ***.***.72.29
          ***.***.72.50
          ***.***.72.59
          ***.***.72.55
          ***.***.72.35
```

I'm using `Google DNS` (`8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`).

I've tried to add some `rule` to block port `53`, unsuccessfully...

There are the rules what I've added to the `firewall` config (`/etc/config/firewall`) and connected to the desired port:

```
config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option name 'block_port_53'
    option dest_port '53'
    option target 'REJECT'
    option proto 'all'

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest_port '53'
    option name 'Guest DNS'
    option src 'guest'
    option enabled '0'

config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option name 'restrict_dns_53_lan'
    option dest_port '53'
    option target 'REJECT'

config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest_port '53'
    option name 'restrict_dns_forward'
    option target 'REJECT'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest 'lan'
```

`Guest DNS` is currently disabled and it is for the `Guest WiFi` (it's the `Guest DNS zone`).

What am I doing wrong?

The main reason to block port `53` is the chinese bots which is trying to rebind my `DNS`. My router's `System Log` is full of this:

```
Jul  4 20:12:53 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406151-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:53 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406163-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:53 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406153-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406166-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406154-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406157-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406156-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406148-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406149-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406155-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:54 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406160-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406164-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406158-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406150-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406161-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406147-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:55 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406152-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:12:56 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406162-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:57 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406159-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:12:58 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 9406165-0-1896986649-4159633587.ns.113-17-184-25-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:24 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376755-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:24 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376759-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:24 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376746-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:15:24 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376741-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:15:24 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376750-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376756-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376752-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376760-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376754-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376758-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
Jul  4 20:15:26 dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4376753-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
```

Please help me get rid of them.

Comment: Bind the DNS daemon only to a internal interface/to an internal IP address. No need for it to answer requests in the public interface/public IP address.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `option proto 'tcpudp'`?  Both the documentation & how this works in iptables implies this is needed, when you specify port numbers.  `tcpudp` is actually the default.  So you don't want to use `all` or `tcp udp` (nor `udp`, as DNS can use both protocols in normal operation).

> [openwrt] Match incoming traffic directed at the given destination port or port range, **if relevant proto is specified**.
>
> [iptables] These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp' is specified. It provides the following options: ... --destination-port

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it. I hope it will works fine. *fingers crossed*